# Kubernetes StatefulSet restart waits if one or more pods are not ready

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a statefulset which constitutes of multiple pods. I have a use case where I need to invoke restart of the STS, I run this: `kubectl rollout restart statefulset mysts`

If I restart the statefulset at a time when one or more pods are in not-ready state, the restart action get queued up. Restart takes effect only after all the pods become ready. This could take long depending on the readiness threshold and the kind of issue the pod is facing.

Is there a way to force restart the statefulset, wherein I don't wait for pods to become ready? I don't want to terminate/delete the pods instead of restarting statefulset. A rolling restart works well for me as it helps avoid outage of the application.

Comment: try setting `spec.podManagementPolicy` to `Parallel`. might not work though.